# Using "sales_order_place_after" event, page does not redirect to success

Tags: php, magento, events, observers

I am writing an observer function to add my custom functionality after the order has been placed. I am using **"sales_order_place_after"** event to do so. The values are being inserted after I place order, but the page is not redirecting to the success page (which states that your order has been placed). If I disable my module or delete this event from config, the redirection works fine. Can anyone tell me where I am mistaken ?

Here is my config.xml code

```
 <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <devengence_module_observer1>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Devengence_Sugarcrm_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>myFunction</method>
                    </devengence_module_observer1>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
```

and my function is

```
public function myFunction($observer){
             $userOrdersModel=Mage::getModel("module/operations");
        $userOrder=$userOrdersModel->load('OrderStatus');
    echo "user Order is ".$userOrder;
        if($userOrder->getId()) //// in case of update
        {
            $userOrdersModel->setId($observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getStatus());
            $userOrdersModel->setIsViewAllowed(0); //update the required value for enable and disable.
            $userOrdersModel->save();
            echo "User Order enable disable status updated";
        }
        else
        { // on new value insertion
            $userOrdersModel->setId($observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getStatus());
        $userOrdersModel->setIsInsertAllowed(false);
        $userOrdersModel->setIsUpdateAllowed(false);
        $userOrdersModel->setIsDeleteAllowed(false);
        $userOrdersModel->setIsViewAllowed(1);
        $userOrdersModel->save();
            echo "it does not exist, a new value has been entered in the database";
        }

        $userOrdersModel=Null;
        $userOrder=Null;


        }
```

The page is not redirecting to success page after the execution of this function. Do I need to explicitly redirect after the event is fired.

Comment: Some of your code can help us figure out the problem. Also check the `var/log` folder for errors

Comment: if you remove the `echo`, does it redirect?

Comment: No, removing echo statements has not effect.